# Why is there no low-precedence equivalent to // in Perl?

Tags: perl, operators, operator-precedence

I suppose this question may strike some as not very important, but I have been wondering why there is no low-precedence defined-or operator in Perl. I suppose there is a reason, since [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or) explicitely mentions the fact.

One instance where I would think it useful is in such a subroutine:

```
sub input_many_data {
    my $x = <> // return;
    do_some_processing_with($x);
    my $y = <> // return;
    do_some_processing_with($y);
    return ( $x, $y );
}

while (1) {
    my ( $x, $y ) = &input_many_data or last;
    do_something_with( $x, $y );
}
```

It does work with `$x = (<> // return)`, but the purpose would be much more obvious, and the code more readable and less error-prone, with something like `($x = <>) dor return`.

Comment: I also always wish such an operator existed. The reason is probably the personal composition of p5p.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never really understood why some porters<sup>[1]</sup> had a problem with it. I think there was a lack of consensus about what to call it (`definedor`, `dor`, `err`), but in retrospect, I'd be tempted to believe the true reason is a lack of comfort with `use feature`. Keep in mind that `use feature` and `//` were added to Perl in the same version.

Or maybe not. You can find the conversation on the [p5 porters mailing list](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.perl.perl5-porters).

---

By the way, the intent of the following is quite obvious:

```
my $x = <>
   // return;
```

It's a bad practice to hide a `return` at the end of a line anyway. Alternatives are:

```
( my $x = <> )
   // return;
```

```
defined( my $x = <> )
   or return;
```

```
my $x = <>;
$x // return;
```

```
my $x = <>;
return if !defined($x);
```

Those of those are compatible with commonly used 5.8.

---

1. Those who work on Perl itself.

Comment: Your comment about hiding a `return` at the end of a line makes sense. But are you aware of a way of making `Perl::Tidy` see the validity of this argument?

Comment: @scozy It's not especially valid. If one doesn't read the entire line of code, one deserves what one gets.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth, For instance, someone may be scanning the subroutine code trying to understand why it returned an empty list. I think it makes sense to have control flow statements stand out.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth, I disagree. You shouldn't have to read every character of a sub to get an idea what it does. As such, exceptional elements of code should stand out. Breaking flow is exceptional.

Comment: @ikegami Not really. Breaking flow should be the assumption, not the exception.

Comment: @Vector Gorgoth, What? A break in the flow is exceptional by definition. If it wasn't exceptional, it wouldn't be breaking the flow. One mean of doing so is even named "exception".

Comment: @ikegami It's called 'flow control' for a reason; that's much of what programming is. A break is simply a particular means of flow control. Always assume that the programmer is exerting that control and you'll make a great many fewer stupid mistakes.